# Cannot replace android library project resources with android application resources

Tags: java, android, overriding

In my android library project, I have:
/res/drawable/redButton.png

And I reference this image file in my library like this:
public class MyLibExample{
    .....
    RadioButton r = new RadioButton(context);
    r.setButtonDrawable(com.mylib.R.drawable.redButton);
}

Now, in my android application project, I have the same res:
/res/drawable/redButton.png
However, this redButton.png is a different graphics file than the one defined in the library.

I do not reference redButton.png in my application.  Instead, I just create an object of type MyLibExample which was defined in the library.

I expected to see the redButton.png from the application, not from the library.  However, the redButton.png from the library is always used.

How do I force the MyLibExample to use the redButton.png from the application?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the id `com.mylib.R.drawable.redButton` is the id defned in mylib. You need the id defined in my app. So in your app code:

```
RadioButton r = (RadioButton)findViewById(com.mylib.R.id.radiobuttonId);
r.setButtonDrawable(com.myapp.R.drawable.redButton);
```